# Easy way to implement multiple filters in Android Mobile App

Tags: flutter, dart, search, filter

I am new to flutter and I am creating an app that contains search data but how to do it with filters like this design[image] I am asking about the business logic of the filters and I want to use bloc for the state management

Answer (score 1):

This question is divided into a lot of parts and I am going to go over them one by one
1> The way your filter data is by using if statements. What you do is make variables and keep their value as a value which accepts all. Like for strings, ''.

2> Now for getting the values in them. You can create a filter page which passes all the values back to the main page

3> Now to take the inputs in various forms:-

i> In the first you can create a row with multiple buttons. In the buttons add a coulmn with the icon or image (You can try fontAwesomeIcons for more icons). When the button is clicked it gets a border (through variables. I would recommend making a custom widget and then using it). You can store all the values selected in a list
ii> The next part is simple. You have to place textFields
iii> Then you need to create a slider using this [https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html\](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html%5C)
iv> You have to repeat the first one but there is a twist.I think you'll only want them to select one value so you can keep a variable whichClicked. In the onClicked, this variable will change and in the design of the button, this variable will determine if it is bordered. The onPressed property will change the value
v> The same as 4th but instead of having borders, you can change the color of the icon

4> Now when these values come back to the home page, apply the filters by looping over the main list of data and then if the values match (DO NOT USE == AS THE DEFAULT VALUES WONT WORK. USE STARTSWITH OR CONTAINS OR > < FOR NUMBERS), store it in list 2 and display list 2. 

If you want code for anything, just comment it. Its very easy to do and you should learn instead of copy pasting the code so that you can make changes and learn something